# How much more hardware for Keerthi's' SMO compared to Platts SMO?

Tags: optimization

Not sure if this is the correct forum to ask this question. Please let me know if it is not. It would be great if anyone can point out if there is any forum where it may be accepted.

This question refers to the paper by Platt:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/sequential-minimal-optimization-a-fast-algorithm-for-training-support-vector-machines/

and by Keerthi:

http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/keerthi-svm.pdf

The Keerthi paper has improved the speed of convergence compare to Platt's paper by changing the search procedure from one threshold to two threshold values. The paper however does not discuss how much more hardware is involved in doing so. Is there anyone who can help to find out this answer?

Comment: Skimming over the papers I don't see any mention of hardware (other than a Pentium II), so I'm not sure what you are aiming at. Looked like a software algorithm to me, but I haven't done an in depth analysis.

Comment: @Arsenal Thank you for you interest. As you can see the basic purpose of using Sequential minimal optimization (SMO) instead of quadratic programming (QP) is to reduce memory requirement so that one can use FPGA kind of hardware to learn SVM. The SMO (Platt) is very good but the second one has improved the time of convergence but they must do so in expense of some extra hardware as they are calculating two thresholds instead of one.